# How do I override my Rotospa's top temperature limit?

Tags: appliances, hot-tub

As with all UL compliant hot-tubs my Rotospa is set to max out at 104º. I am reasonably confident that there's a straightforward way to override this limit (I've seen YouTube videos for how to do it on other brands of hot-tubs).

Would love some advice or a link to a demo of how to do this. I understand that this will most likely void my warranty - I'm unconcerned by this fact.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find the temperature sensor. Engineer a way to hold it a little colder than the water.

Comment: @brhans The solutions for the other spas only involve making modifications to the circuit board (they are not mechanical in nature). Are you saying the Rotospa is different in this respect?

Comment: No, I'm just giving you an option which doesn't require you to have any understanding of the thermostat circuit.

Comment: I see. Ok, thanks - I'll consider it.

Comment: We would probably need the model number of the spa, most are thermocouple controlled the problem may be shifting the input could also display the wrong value. This might be a good one for the electronics stack exchange,

Comment: You do realize there is a safety hazard in having higher temps?  Be sure that whatever you do you can undo before you sell the house. https://rhtubs.com/resources/why-hot-tub-temperatures-max-out-at-104-degrees/